# How to access current chunk context programmaticaly from CustomItemWriter?

Tags: java, spring-batch

I have a job with a [multi-threaded chunk-oriented step](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/3.0.x/reference/html/scalability.html#multithreadedStep) and I need to count how many written items satisfy some business rules. (PS: For legacy reasons, I'm using Spring Batch 3.0.x)

I have to keep in mind that if a rollback happens, then previous already counted items within the same transaction (i.e. same chunk) must be ignored. So I can't just update JobExecutionContext straight from Writer, rather I update an attribute in ChunkContext and use a *CustomChunkListener* to only update the JobExecutionContext after the chunk succeeds (as you can see in code below).

Before making the step multi-threaded, I had following implementation that worked as expected (I simplified the code as much as I could to focus on the issue):

*CustomItemWriter*

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<String[]> {

    private ChunkContext chunkContext;

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends String[]> items) throws Exception {
        for (String[] item : items) {
            ((AtomicLong)this.chunkContext.getAttribute("chunkCounter")).incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    @BeforeChunk
    private void beforeChunk(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        this.chunkContext = chunkContext;
    }
}
```

*CustomChunkListener*

```
public class CustomChunkListener extends ChunkListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public void beforeChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        context.setAttribute("chunkCounter", new AtomicLong());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterChunk(ChunkContext context) {
        ((AtomicLong)context.getStepContext().getJobExecutionContext().get("jobCounter")).addAndGet(((AtomicLong)context.getAttribute("chunkCounter")).get());
    }
}
```

*CustomJobListener*

```
public class CustomJobListener extends JobExecutionListenerSupport {

    @Override
    public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        jobExecution.getExecutionContext().put("jobCounter", new AtomicLong());
    }

    @Override
    public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
        System.out.println("jobCounter = " + jobExecution.getExecutionContext().get("jobCounter"));
    }
}
```

However, when I configured the job to run the step in a multi-threaded fashion, the counter wasn't being updated properly and I know that it was because of the way I was getting access to the ChunkContext in the CustomItemWriter.

The bean CustomItemWriter is of "step scope" (as far as I know, there is no "chunk scope" available), so each time a thread started a new ChunkContext, the method beforeChunk in CustomItemWriter was overwriting the previous ChunkContext and was messing everything up (previously counted would then be gone, since I had lost reference to previous ChunkContext instances).

So, I managed to fix the issue by using ThreadLocal, like below:

*CustomItemWriter  (v2)*

```
public class CustomItemWriter implements ItemWriter<String[]> {

    private ThreadLocal<ChunkContext> chunkContext = new ThreadLocal<ChunkContext>();

    @Override
    public void write(List<? extends String[]> items) throws Exception {
        for (String[] item : items) {
            ((AtomicLong)this.chunkContext.get().getAttribute("chunkCounter")).incrementAndGet();
        }
    }

    @BeforeChunk
    private void beforeChunk(ChunkContext chunkContext) {
        this.chunkContext.set(chunkContext);
    }
}
```

Although I have managed to solve the problem, I'm wondering if there is a better way to access the current ChunkContext (for the current thread) from within the CustomItemWriter. Is there a way to get it programmaticaly? To do it "the Spring way", perhaps a [new] Chunk Scope should be implemented in newer versions of Spring Batch?

PS: Also, although the problem is solved, I thought it would be helpful to write this question so it can help someone with the same needs.

Comment: Even though you solved your issue, you asked if there is better way. I added an answer + some recommendations. If this helps, please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Although I have managed to solve the problem, I'm wondering if there is a better way to access the current ChunkContext (for the current thread) from within the CustomItemWriter

No, I see no other way to do that. However, it is not recommended to play with the chunk context in a multi-threaded step. This context is a mutable state which is shared between all threads processing the step (with all the nasty bugs of using  shared mutable state in a multi-threaded environment).

The documentation will be updated in that regard, see https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/591/files#diff-177ad333794c9242aaa9ec2d0bec1842R147-R150.